# Discrepancy between sha256sum executable and PyCrypto library

Tags: python, command-line, sha256

I am trying to take the SHA256 sum of an ASCII encoded string. To begin, I tried the `sha256sum` executable:

```
$ echo foo | sha256sum
b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c
```

But when I use the `PyCrypto` library, I get something different:

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
h = SHA256.new();
h.update('foo');
print(h.hexdigest());
```

I get the following:

```
c5aac592460a9ac7845e341090f6f9c81f201b63e5338ee8948a6fe6830c55dc
```

I suspect I am missing something about the first one, that is, `echo foo` might have a delimiter or something, but I haven't been able to figure out what.

What is different about these two situations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command `echo foo` adds a newline at the end of the output, you should use the `-n` option:

```
$ echo -n foo | sha256sum
2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae  -
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha256('foo').hexdigest()
'2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae'
```